# SSH tunnel through second IP of a server

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I use [`sshuttle`](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) in Ubuntu to create a SSH tunnel with my VPS. My VPS has 6 assigned IP addresses, but if I use any of the 6 IPs to build an SSH tunnel, my assigned tunnel IP address is always the VPS primary IP address rather than the IP address I used to connect.

How can I make a SSH tunnel with the secondary IP address of a VPS?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `sshuttle`, but from skimming its usage page and some of its source, I don't believe it supports that.

If you were using `ssh` directly (with the `-L` or `-R` flags), you'd need to supply an address as the optional first argument (referred to as `bind_address` in the manual page). For example, `ssh -L 50513:example.com:80` will choose an address to bind to on the local side automatically—if you want to force it to bind to `203.0.113.5`, you would use `ssh -L 203.0.113.5:50513:example.com:80`.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure jumphosts using a ProxyCommand in ~/.ssh/config, assign hostnames for nics in /etc/hosts

[ssh-chaining](http://www.bsdnow.tv/tutorials/ssh-chaining)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to bind which interface/IP you want to the service.

For example, in SSH you can modify the ListenAddress in your sshd_config file.

Comment: -1: the question is not about getting `sshd` to listen on a different address, but getting an `ssh` tunnel to bind to a different address.